# Downsides & Alternatives - JS method chaining

Tags: javascript, replace

I am doing something along these lines in some code I am writing

```
txt = txt.replaceAll('\n','').replaceAll('<b>','[bold]').replaceAll('</b>','[/bold]')
.replaceAll('<strong>','[bold]').replaceAll('</strong>','[/bold]')....
```

where replaceAll is a String.prototype extension.  This works perfectly, but I am wondering -

are there any downsides to chaining too many methods in this way?  Would it perhaps be better to use a regex that does the job in a "oner"?  If so what would the regex look like? (I am not terribly good with regexs)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is totally fine and trying to assemble a regex that would handle all these cases would be both convoluted as well as less efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fine. The regex alternative is also quite straight-forward, you basically just have to use an alternation and be sure to escape what needs escaping: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/IQIvEWa/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/IQIvEWa/1/edit)

```
var replacements = {
    '\n':        '',
    '<b>':       '[bold]'
    '</b>':      '[/bold]',
    '<strong>':  '[bold]',
    '</strong>': '[/bold]'
    // ...
};
txt = txt.replace(/\n|<b>|<\/b>|<strong>|<\/strong>/g, function(m) {
    return m in replacements ? replacements[m] : m;
});
```

Comment: Thank you! @Michael Geary.  I am accepting T.J. Crowder's answer because of the regex.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to chain those together. But don't put them all on one line. It's much easier to read if you reformat the code:

```
txt = txt
    .replaceAll( '\n', '' )
    .replaceAll( '<b>', '[bold]' )
    .replaceAll( '</b>', '[/bold]' )
    .replaceAll( '<strong>', '[bold]' )
    .replaceAll( '</strong>', '[/bold]' );
```

This same style is useful in jQuery chains:

```
$('<div>Test</div>')
    .css({ fontSize: '16px' })
    .attr({ title: 'Test' })
    .appendTo( 'body' );
```